# Espresso Tests cannot access class file

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I get the following errors where i try to run a ui test.

```
/Users/etiennelawlor/workspace/MovieHub/app/src/androidTest/java/com/etiennelawlor/moviehub/MoviesFragmentTest.java 

Error:(34, 28) error: cannot access AppCompatActivity class file for android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity not found 

Error:(34, 58) error: cannot infer type arguments for ActivityTestRule<> 

Error:(41, 41) error: cannot access IdlingResource class file for android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource not found 

Error:(51, 40) error: cannot access RecyclerView class file for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView not found 

Error:Execution failed for task ‘:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac’.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is my Test class : https://github.com/lawloretienne/MovieHub/blob/226492727e4d467b337ed4b689edb05eec0368c2/app/src/androidTest/java/com/etiennelawlor/moviehub/MoviesFragmentTest.java

Am I missing something?

Here is my Gradle file

https://github.com/lawloretienne/MovieHub/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: I am not sure but try to exclude recyclerview from espresso in gradle.

Comment: I can comment out that line and then that error wont get thrown but there are other errors that will still get thrown.

Comment: Can you post your gradle

Comment: I just updated to include the link to my Gradle file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `build.gradle` explicitly excludes all dependencies of the production apk, which in turn, excludes the compat library from the instrumentation apk. 
I am not sure why this is required because I have never experienced that bug mentioned in the comment.

Basically, removing this block:

```
configurations.implementation.dependencies.all { implementationDependency ->
    println "Excluding implementation dependency: ${implementationDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestImplementation.dependencies.all { androidTestImplementationDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestImplementation.exclude module: "${implementationDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

will fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. I am gunna wait until i can create a bounty for this question and reward you with the bounty because i have struggled to fix this issue for months.

Comment: I have opened an issue here
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/issues/84

Comment: Hey, could you explain how you figured it out that script block causing the problem?? 

This problem also occurring with the codelabs example.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding the solution.